# How to CreateObject for Uri Type

Tags: c#, silverlight, uri

```
private static object CreateObject(Type itemType)
{
    try
    {
        if (itemType.FullName == "System.Uri")
        {
            ????
        }

        return Activator.CreateInstance(itemType);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return itemType.GetConstructor(new Type[] { }).Invoke(new object[] { });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a `Uri` is immutable (much like string), it doesn't make sense to create one without a value. When you know the Uri, use the regular constructor, for example `new Uri(string)` - or use `TryCreate`.

Btw - you could also test: `if(itemType == typeof(Uri))`